# How to create web application Maven archetype for Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, maven-archetype

I have a working or mostly working POM that fetches all and exactly just the JARs that interest me for writing a Facelets application. I'm using m2eclipse. When I import the newly Maven-created application, it comes in cleanly and more or less as expected, however, it is not like a Dynamic Web Project in that when I try to run it, it offers no Run As -> Run on Server option.

I have studied other Maven-generated Eclipse projects that do work (but don't come set up with the JAR combination I want) in the sense that they can be run on Server. For example, this one works, but it's not got the JARs I want:

> mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp \
>           -DgroupId=package-name -DartifactId=project-name

Do I need to create a custom archetype artifactId in imitation of the *...-DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp...* I see in in the command above and, if so, how?

Or is it merely a function of the filesystem set up by that archetype? I see that the project I've generated (webapp1)...

```
webapp1
|-- src
|   `-- main
|       |-- java
|       |-- resources
|       `-- webapp
|           `-- WEB-INF
`-- target
    `-- classes`
```

... has different content than one generated using *maven-archetype-webapp*, but I don't know how to force *mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse* to generate that (or whether that's what's telling Eclipse this is a web application and it should set up for Run As -> Run on Server).

```
simpleWeb
|-- src
|   `-- main
|       |-- java
|       |   `-- com
|       |       `-- mytutorial
|       |-- resources
|       |   `-- com
|       |       `-- mytutorial
|       `-- webapp
|           |-- META-INF
|           |-- pages
|           `-- WEB-INF
`-- target
    |-- classes
    |   `-- com
    |       `-- mytutorial
    |-- maven-archiver
    |-- META-INF
    |   `-- maven
    |       `-- com.mytutorial
    |           `-- simpleWeb
    |-- pages
    |-- simpleWeb
    |   |-- META-INF
    |   |-- pages
    |   `-- WEB-INF
    |       |-- classes
    |       |   `-- com
    |       |       `-- mytutorial
    |       `-- lib
    |-- surefire
    |-- test-classes
    `-- WEB-INF
        |-- classes
        |   `-- com
        |       `-- mytutorial
        `-- lib
```

Profuse thanks to anyone who can launch me on the path of enlightenment.

Russ

P.S. Here's my *pom.xml*:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.etretatlogiciels.webapp1</groupId>
  <artifactId>webapp1</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>webapp1 Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <commons-beanutils-version>    1.8.3        </commons-beanutils-version>
    <commons-codec-version>        1.4          </commons-codec-version>
    <commons-collections-version>  3.2.1        </commons-collections-version>
    <commons-digester-version>     2.1          </commons-digester-version>
    <commons-discovery-version>    0.4          </commons-discovery-version>
    <commons-logging-version>      1.1.1        </commons-logging-version>
    <jsf-facelets-version>         1.1.15       </jsf-facelets-version>
    <myfaces-version>              2.0.4        </myfaces-version>
    <richfaces-version>            3.3.3.Final  </richfaces-version>
  </properties>

  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>
      <name>JBoss Public Maven Repository Group</name>
      <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/</url>
      <layout>default</layout>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- Apache Commons -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
      <version>${commons-beanutils-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
      <version>${commons-codec-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
      <version>${commons-collections-version}</version>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
      <version>${commons-digester-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-discovery</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-discovery</artifactId>
      <version>${commons-discovery-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
      <version>${commons-logging-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Facelets -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.facelets</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsf-facelets</artifactId>
      <version>${jsf-facelets-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- MyFaces -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>myfaces-api</artifactId>
      <version>${myfaces-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>myfaces-impl</artifactId>
      <version>${myfaces-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- RichFaces -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.richfaces.framework</groupId>
      <artifactId>richfaces-api-jsf2</artifactId>
      <version>${richfaces-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.richfaces.framework</groupId>
      <artifactId>richfaces-impl-jsf2</artifactId>
      <version>${richfaces-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.richfaces.framework</groupId>
      <artifactId>richfaces-ui-jsf2</artifactId>
      <version>${richfaces-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JUnit -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>webapp1</finalName>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/java</directory>
        <includes>
          <include>**/*.java</include>
        </includes>
      </resource>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
        <configuration>
        <source>1.5</source>
        <target>1.5</target>
      </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>richfaces</id>
        <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <repositories>
          <repository>
            <id>maven2.repository</id>
            <name>Repository for Maven by Maven</name>
            <url>http://repo2.maven.org/maven2</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <releases>
              <enabled>true</enabled>
              <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
          </repository>
          <repository>
            <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
            <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/1</url>
            <layout>legacy</layout>
            <releases>
              <enabled>true</enabled>
              <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
          </repository>
          <repository>
            <id>JBoss Repository Old</id>
            <name>Repository for Maven by JBoss</name>
            <url>http://repository.jboss.org/maven2</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <releases>
              <enabled>true</enabled>
              <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
          </repository>
          <repository>
            <id>JBoss Repository Nexus</id>
            <name>Repository for Maven by JBoss</name>
            <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <releases>
              <enabled>true</enabled>
              <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
          </releases>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>

</project>
```

Comment: What is you aim? Your description of problem is too complex. If you want to run you war in apache tomcat you can add apache tomcat server in eclipse: window->show view->others->server->servers. Then link your project to tomcat (i used file synchronization - but my way is not the easiest).

Comment: Thanks. I suppose I don't know exactly what I want in that I don't know the space between Maven and Eclipse. My objective is to bridge that space with understanding, then write about it for others (in addition actually to creating a web application). I already have a Tomcat server in my workspace, but there's Eclipse wiring, normally handled by creating a Dynamic Web Project, that must be done. As I'm letting Maven create the project, none of that wiring is getting done. I've compared my POM to other POMs for which the wiring does appear to work and cannot reveal the difference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've had exactly the same problem. None of existing archetypes matched my needs. If I created (from eclipse) a project from custom archetype it wouldn't become dynamic web project.
If you run mvn -Dwtpversion=2.0 eclipse:eclipse it again adds all sorts of things you don't need.
So after investigating I eventually found out what defeines "dynamic web project". It's a bunch of directories and files of in .settings directory and entries in .project.

So what you need to do is the following:
1.) create an empty (non-maven) dynamic web project from within eclipse.
2.) Without adding any files or any other changes, inspect on the file system the following files created by eclipse (relative to the project directory):
.project
.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs
.settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.prefs.xml
.settings/org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui.superType.name
.settings/org.eclipse.jst.jsp.core.prefs
.settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml
.settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.component
.settings/org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui.superType.container

3.) Copy these files to your archetype-resources directory for your custom archetime
4.) Edit and generalise the copied files (replacing actual project names with ${artifactId} etc...
5.) In your archetype-metadata.xml file add:

```
<fileSet encoding="UTF-8" filtered="true">
  <directory></directory>
<includes>
  <include>.project</include>
</includes>
</fileSet>
<fileSet encoding="UTF-8" filtered="true">
  <directory>.settings</directory>
</fileSet>
```

Without this maven will not upload files starting with ".*"

6.) Voila!. Install and deploy your archetype and try again. It worked for me.

Comment: Super! Thanks very much, my friend!

Answer (score 7):

how about just configuring maven-eclipse-plugin in your archetype-resources/pom.xml?

```
<build>
    <finalName>archetype-javaee5-webapp</finalName>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

this will create a web-able project in eclipse

Comment: I thank you for this response. Ultimately, I abandoned Maven for Ivy + ant. I know it's anathema to admit this in a totally Maven world, but hopefully the thought police won't ever find me ;-) If I ever have occasion to go back on my decision, I'll be trying out this solution.

Comment: This is the solution I use to have my web apps recognized as such in Eclipse. Works as expected.

Comment: Make sure you install Maven Integration for Eclipse WTP (m2e-wtp)

http://marketplace.eclipse.org/node/441371#.URhKr1qje1k

Answer (score 2):

To create a Dynamic Web Project for Eclipse, you need to do this :

1) generate a project using something like :

> mvn archetype:generate >optional arguments like -Dfilter=webapp-j2ee<

This will help you in generating a maven project in interactive mode and you won't have to type in options for artifactId, groupId etc.

Note: It still might not be a Dynamic Web Project, in my case, it never is...
(I guess basically it depends upon the archetype-artifactId that you have used and I haven't found the one which will generate a Dynamic Web module by itself for a basic j2ee app which will use only jsp's, servlet's and nothing more)

2) Now to generate the project file for eclipse, use this command:

> mvn -Dwtpversion=2.0 eclipse:eclipse

This will generate a project file which will have the required project facet set. So when you import it in your Eclipse IDE, it will be a "Dynamic Web Module".

Note: Now if you are looking for a particular version of the "Dynamic Web Module" then you need to configure your POM. The version depends upon following tag within your build tag:

```
<code>
<build>
......
  <plugins>
  ........
    <plugin>
      <groupId>         org.apache.maven.plugins  </groupId>
      <artifactId>      maven-compiler-plugin     </artifactId>
      <version>         2.3.2                     </version>
      <configuration>
                   <source>   1.6     </source>
                   <target>   1.6     </target>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  .........
  </plugins>
.......
</build>
</code>
```

Now, if the source and target are set to 1.6 (like in this case) then the Dynamic Web Module 2.5 will get selected. Otherwise, it will be 2.4 for compiler-plugin 1.4 and so on.